# How can I use JQuery in my Google Chrome extension with Manifest 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I am trying to figure out how I can use JQuery in my background.js for Google Chrome extension development for Manifest 3. All of the other answers I have found are for Manifest 2.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research and time spent trying to figure out how to make this work I figured it out.

To add jquery to your background.js through the use of content functions, you need to add the following to your manifest.

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "css":["/css/jquery/jquery-ui.min.css", "/css/jquery/jquery-ui.structure.min.css"],
      "js":["/js/jquery/jquery-3.6.0.min.js", "/js/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"],
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
```

Comment: It doesn't add jquery to the background script. It adds to the content scripts. You can't use jQuery in a ManifestV3 background script because there is no DOM.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm using it in my background.js but through content functions. I should have clarified

Comment: This is not what "in" means.